# I can not make my Skyline algorithm use right my ''delete'' method and delete all the right Points of my List ( List with <<Random>> Points)

Tags: java, list

```
public void findSkyline1(ListDoublePoints list)
{
    DoublePoint p = list.first;
    DoublePoint q = list.first;

    while (p!=null ){
        while (q!=null )
        {

            if (p.x < q.x)
            {
                if(p.y<=q.y)
                {
                    list.delete(q);

                }
            }
            else if (p.x == q.x)
            {
                if (p.y <q.y)
                {
                    list.delete(q);

                }
                else if (p.y > q.y)
                {
                    list.delete(p);
                    break;
                }
                }
            else
            {
                list.delete(p);
                break;
            }
            //end of if 

            q=q.next;
        }

        p=p.next;
    }

}
```

.....................

```
public DoublePoint delete(DoublePoint del)
{
    if (del == first)
        first = del.next;
    else
       del.previous.next = del.next;

    if (del == last)
        last = del.previous;
    else 
        del.next.previous = del.previous;
    return del;
}
```

.........
i have put a list of Random double numbers.My Main calls an algorithm and uses  a skyline algorithm(in my own way).In my class about ''ListDoublePoints'' i have a method that deletes the ''DoublePoints'' i don't need.
So,i want to make my delete method work in my skyline algorithm.It works only for a small number of DoublePoints,so some that i don't need...still exist.!Any ideas?

Comment: While I'm sure this code is terribly interesting, no one is going to read it unless you describe your problem a little more in depth. What have you tried? What happened when you tried that? What did you want to have happen?

Comment: Sorry i am new in here.So,if i write a comment here,none would read that too?

Comment: You should edit your original post to describe what you're trying to do.